# Route data into Separate Excel sheets baded on Operator Input Box Variable?

Tags: excel, vba

Ugggh, I don't really have much experience with this, but here goes:  I have this script that I'm working on fo like a week, and I'm stuck.  What I am trying to do, is export measurement data from a PC DMIS part program into an Excel workbook.  I got that far.  Now what I am trying to do is modify what I had to take info from an operator inputbox and route the data into separate sheets within that workbook (by mold cavity number in this case).  Here is what I have going (the two blocks that I have marked, are what I am trying to add to what I originally had):

```
'Option Explicit
Sub Main 


'xl Declarations
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkbooks As Object
Dim xlWorkbook As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim count As Integer
Dim xlWorksheets As String 
Dim xlWorksheet As String 

'pcdlrn declarations And Open ppg
Dim App As Object
Set App = CreateObject("PCDLRN.Application")
Dim Part As Object
Set Part = App.ActivePartProgram
Dim Cmds As Object
Set Cmds = Part.Commands
Dim Cmd As Object
Dim DCmd As Object
Dim DcmdID As Object
Dim fs As Object 
Dim DimID As String 
Dim ReportDim As String
Dim CheckDim As String 
Dim Cavity As String  
Dim myValue As String 
Dim message, title, defaultValue As String 
message = "Cavity" 
title = "cavity" 
defaultValue = "1" 
myValue = InputBox(message, title, defaultValue)
If myValue = "" Then myValue = defaultValue 

'Check To see If results file exists
FilePath = "C:\Excel PC DMIS\3K170 B2A\"
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
ResFileExists = fs.fileexists(FilePath & Part.partname & ".xls")

'Open Excel And Base form
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWorkbooks = xlapp.Workbooks
If ResFileExists = False Then
    TempFilename = FilePath & "Loop Template.xls"
Else
    TempFilename = FilePath & Part.partname & ".xls"
End If

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")            'Error start???

Set xlWorkbook = xlWorkbooks.Open(TempFilename)
Set xlSheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set xlsheets = xlworkbook.worksheets

Dim sh As Worksheet, flg As Boolean
For Each sh In xlworkbook.worksheets
     If sh.Name = myValue Then flg = True: Exit For 
Next

If flg = False Then 
   xlsheets.Add.Name = myValue
End If

Set xlSheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(myValue)
                                                   'error End ?????

If ResFileExists = False Then
    RCount=6
    CCount=3
    xlSheet.Range("B1").Value = Part.PartName
    xlSheet.Range("A6").Value = Date() & " " & Time()
    xlSheet.Range("B6").Value = "Inspector Name"
    For Each Cmd In Cmds
        'Eliminate DATDEF's
        If Cmd.Type <> 1299 Then
            'Do Dimensions
            If Cmd.IsDimension Then
                If Cmd.Type = DIMENSION_START_LOCATION Or Cmd.Type = DIMENSION_TRUE_START_POSITION Then
                    Set DcmdID = Cmd.DimensionCommand
                      DimID = DcmdID.ID
                      ReportDim = Cmd.GetText ( OUTPUT_TYPE, 0)
                End If
                If Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_START_LOCATION And Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_END_LOCATION And _
                    Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_TRUE_START_POSITION And Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_TRUE_END_POSITION Then
                    Set DCmd = Cmd.DimensionCommand
                    CheckDim = Cmd.GetText ( OUTPUT_TYPE, 0)
                    If CheckDim <> "" Then
                            ReportDim = CheckDim
                    End If
                    If ReportDim = "BOTH" Or ReportDim = "REPORT" Then
                        If DCmd.ID = "" Then
                                xlSheet.Cells(5,CCount).Value = DimID & "."& DCmd.AxisLetter
                        Else
                                xlSheet.Cells(5,CCount).Value = DCmd.ID & "." & "M"
                        End If
                                xlSheet.Cells(2,CCount).Value = DCmd.Nominal
                                xlSheet.Cells(3,CCount).Value = DCmd.Plus
                                xlSheet.Cells(4,CCount).Value = DCmd.Minus
                                'Measured Or Deviation With check For True Position
                    If DCmd.AxisLetter <> "TP" Then
                                  xlSheet.Cells(6,CCount).Value = DCmd.Measured
                Else
                                  xlSheet.Cells(6,CCount).Value = DCmd.Deviation
                End If
                                'Add Min/Max For Profile dimensions
                                If Cmd.Type = 1118 Or Cmd.Type = 1105 Then
                                  CCount=CCount+1
                                  xlSheet.Cells(5,CCount).Value = DCmd.ID & "." & "Max"
                                  xlSheet.Cells(2,CCount).Value = DCmd.Nominal
                                  xlSheet.Cells(3,CCount).Value = DCmd.Plus
                                  xlSheet.Cells(4,CCount).Value = DCmd.Minus
                                  xlSheet.Cells(6,CCount).Value = DCmd.Max
                                  CCount=CCount+1
                                  xlSheet.Cells(5,CCount).Value = DCmd.ID & "." & "Min"
                                  xlSheet.Cells(2,CCount).Value = DCmd.Nominal
                                  xlSheet.Cells(3,CCount).Value = DCmd.Plus
                                  xlSheet.Cells(4,CCount).Value = DCmd.Minus
                                  xlSheet.Cells(6,CCount).Value = DCmd.Min
                                End If
                                CCount=CCount+1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            'Do GDT
            If Cmd.Type = 184 Then
                  ReportDim = Cmd.GetText ( OUTPUT_TYPE, 0)
                  If ReportDim = "BOTH" Or ReportDim = "REPORT" Then
                        xlSheet.Cells(5,CCount).Value = Cmd.GetText (ID, 0) & "." & "FCF"
                        xlSheet.Cells(2,CCount).Value = "0"
                        xlSheet.Cells(3,CCount).Value = Cmd.GetText (LINE2_PLUSTOL, 1)
                        xlSheet.Cells(4,CCount).Value = "0"
                        xlSheet.Cells(6,CCount).Value = Cmd.GetText (LINE2_DEV, 1)
                        CCount=CCount+1
                  End If
            End If
        End If
    Next Cmd


Else

'Find first Open column.
RCount=6
Found=0
Do Until Found = 1
RCount = RCount + 1
If xlSheet.Cells(RCount,1).Value = "" Then
Found=1
End If
Loop

xlSheet.Cells(RCount,1).Value = Date() & " " & Time()
xlSheet.Cells(RCount,2).Value= "Inspector Name"

'Fill In measured data
CCount = 3
    For Each Cmd In Cmds
        'Eliminate DATDEF's
        If Cmd.Type <> 1299 Then
            'Do Dimensions
            If Cmd.IsDimension Then
                If Cmd.Type = DIMENSION_START_LOCATION Or Cmd.Type = DIMENSION_TRUE_START_POSITION Then
                    Set DcmdID = Cmd.DimensionCommand
                      DimID = DcmdID.ID
                      ReportDim = Cmd.GetText ( OUTPUT_TYPE, 0)
                End If
                If Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_START_LOCATION And Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_END_LOCATION And _
                    Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_TRUE_START_POSITION And Cmd.Type <> DIMENSION_TRUE_END_POSITION Then
                    Set DCmd = Cmd.DimensionCommand
                    CheckDim = Cmd.GetText ( OUTPUT_TYPE, 0)
                    If CheckDim <> "" Then
                            ReportDim = CheckDim
                    End If
                    If ReportDim = "BOTH" Or ReportDim = "REPORT" Then
                                'Measured Or Deviation With check For True Position
                            If DCmd.AxisLetter <> "TP" Then
                                  xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = DCmd.Measured
                Else
                                  xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = DCmd.Deviation
                End If
                                'Add Min/Max For Profile dimensions
                                If Cmd.Type = 1118 Or Cmd.Type = 1105 Then
                                  CCount=CCount+1
                                  xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = DCmd.Max
                                  CCount=CCount+1
                                  xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = DCmd.Min
                                End If
                       Ccount=Ccount+1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            'Do GDT
            If Cmd.Type = 184 Then
                  ReportDim = Cmd.GetText ( OUTPUT_TYPE, 0)
                  If ReportDim = "BOTH" Or ReportDim = "REPORT" Then
                        xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = Cmd.GetText (ID, 0) & "." & "FCF"
                        xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = "0"
                        xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = Cmd.GetText (LINE2_PLUSTOL, 1)
                        xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = "0"
                        xlSheet.Cells(RCount,CCount).Value = Cmd.GetText (LINE2_DEV, 1)
                        CCount=CCount+1
                  End If
            End If
        End If
    Next Cmd
End If


'Save And Cleanup
Set xlSheet = Nothing 
SaveName = FilePath & Part.partname & ".xls"
If ResFileExists = False Then
xlWorkBook.SaveAs SaveName
Else
xlWorkBook.Save
End If
xlWorkbook.Close
Set xlWorkbook = Nothing 
xlWorkbooks.Close 
Set xlWorkbooks = Nothing 
xlApp.Quit 
Set xlApp = Nothing

LabelEnd:

End Sub
```

Comment: I am pretty sure my problem is within that second block, but cannot figure it out for the life of me.  A little help from the pros??

Comment: Are you running this in excel? If Yes, you don't need the second instance of excel: it will be easier to run in the same instance as your macro is running.

Comment: Oops, no, I guess I should have been clearer.  This is a Basic Script inserted into a PC DMIS part program, outside of Excel

Comment: `Dim sh As Worksheets` should be `Dim sh As Worksheet`

Comment: Yeah, that what someone else said, but if I do that, then I get an error on the line underneath it "Object Required", hmmm

Comment: `For Each sh In xlWorkbook.Worksheets`

Comment: Woo Hoo!!  Thanks to everyone who offered help. @Tim Williams,and others whose comments seem to have disappeared. Finally got it almost buttoned up, and it is doing what I need it to. (Updated above) All I have left to figure out is why it is opening new instance of Excel in the task manager with each run, and draining memory.  It should automatically close Excel out at the end of the script, right??

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function which can help with getting a reference to a particular sheet:

```
Function GetSheet(wb As Workbook, wsName As String, _
     Optional CreateIfMissing As Boolean = True)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(wsName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ws Is Nothing And CreateIfMissing Then
        Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = wsName
    End If

    Set GetSheet = ws
End Function
```

It has an option (on by default) to create the sheet if it's not found.

Comment: I'd add to your rep, but am not seeing how